# this.props.myActionCreator throws 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, flux

Just to mention, I did not find an answers for my particular situation on similar post.

My app allows a user to get a city's weather along with a relevant packing list for that weather.

I want to make each city's card deletable and have an 'X' placed that should call an updateTerms action creator, which would in turn remove it from the users list and update the dom.

The callback seems to fire, but **this.props.updateTerms** throws **TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
    at handleDeleteCard **

a_result_card.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ATodoList from './a_Todo_List';
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup';
import { bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import { updateTerms } from '../actions';

class AResultCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = { cityName : '' }; 
        this.handleDeleteCard = this.handleDeleteCard.bind(this);
    }

    handleDeleteCard(event) { // I NEED TO CALL THIS WITH THE KEY
        //So THAT I CAN REMOVE IT FROM THE USERS TERM LIST
        event.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        this.props.updateTerms(cityName, "delete");
    }

    renderWeather(cityData) {
        function calcAverageTemp(days) {
            let reduced = days.reduce((sum,day) => {
               return sum + day.main.temp_max;
            }, 0);
            return Math.floor(reduced / cityData.list.length);
        };
        function calcAverageHumidity(days) {
            let reduced = days.reduce((sum,day) => {
               return sum + day.main.humidity;
            }, 0);
            return Math.floor(reduced / cityData.list.length);
        };
        const avgTempK = calcAverageTemp(cityData.list);
        const cityName = cityData.city.name;
        const avgTempF = Math.floor((avgTempK * 1.8) - 459.67 );
        const avgHumidity = calcAverageHumidity(cityData.list);

        return (
            <li key={cityName} className="result-card">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="">
                        <div className="weather-details">
                            <div className="card-heading">
                                <span className="weather-detail detail-title">{cityName}</span>
                                <span className="weather-detail">{avgTempF} &#176;F</span>
                                <span className="weather-detail">H: {avgHumidity}%</span>
                                <span className="weather-detail delete-card-icon" onClick={handleDeleteCard}>X</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ATodoList avgTempF={avgTempF} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="results">
                <CSSTransitionGroup
                    transitionName="example"
                    transitionEnterTimeout={150}
                    transitionLeaveTimeout={150}>

                {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
                </CSSTransitionGroup>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({weather, userTerms}) {
    return ({
            weather,
            userTerms
        });
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ updateTerms }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AResultCard);
```

Comment: Can you try calling the onClick function like this - `onClick = {this.handleDeleteCard}`

Comment: This was part of the solution, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your `handleDeleteCard` function like

```
<span className="weather-detail delete-card-icon" onClick={this.handleDeleteCard}>X</span>
```

since it belongs to the context of the `React Component` and not the `renderWeather` function

Also bind the renderWeather function

```
renderWeather = (cityData) => {
    function calcAverageTemp(days) {
        let reduced = days.reduce((sum,day) => {
           return sum + day.main.temp_max;
        }, 0);
        return Math.floor(reduced / cityData.list.length);
    };
    function calcAverageHumidity(days) {
        let reduced = days.reduce((sum,day) => {
           return sum + day.main.humidity;
        }, 0);
        return Math.floor(reduced / cityData.list.length);
    };
    const avgTempK = calcAverageTemp(cityData.list);
    const cityName = cityData.city.name;
    const avgTempF = Math.floor((avgTempK * 1.8) - 459.67 );
    const avgHumidity = calcAverageHumidity(cityData.list);

    return (
        <li key={cityName} className="result-card">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="">
                    <div className="weather-details">
                        <div className="card-heading">
                            <span className="weather-detail detail-title">{cityName}</span>
                            <span className="weather-detail">{avgTempF} &#176;F</span>
                            <span className="weather-detail">H: {avgHumidity}%</span>
                            <span className="weather-detail delete-card-icon" onClick={this.handleDeleteCard}>X</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ATodoList avgTempF={avgTempF} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked. I had forgotten than using the arrow operator handles scope differently. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I'd like to pass the cityName into the action creator, but it is currently generated inside of renderWeather. If you have any ideas about organizing my data better, I'd be open to suggestions. :)